# XPath evaluating to true or false instead of selected element

Tags: xml, xpath, google-docs, google-docs-api

I am attempting to pull pricing from this website into Google Docs using ImportXML. The code for the element is

```
<div class="col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 price"   style="color:#007b29">$644.96</div>
```

My formula is

```
=IMPORTXML(I2,"//div[@class='col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 price']/@style='color:#007b29'")
```

Obviously, the link for the website is located in I2. However, this doesn't return the element ($644.96), but TRUE instead. Obviously I'm missing something here, and it feels like it should be fairly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

ImportXML is returning true because your XPath expression is a test evaluating to true.   Move `@style='color:#007b29'` into a predicate to instead have the XPath expression evaluate to the `div` with the given `@class` and `@style` attribute values:

```
//div[@class='col-xs-8 col-sm-7 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 price'][@style='color:#007b29']
```